# Dini's Derivative of a locally Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a locally Lipschitz function and let $v \in \mathbb R^n$. By Rademacher's theorem we know that the gradient $\nabla f$ exists almost everywhere (i.e. it $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere).

We know that the following statement holds:

If $\nabla f(x)$ exists, then $ D_v f := \nabla f(x) . v \ge 0$.

Does this imply the same inequality for the Dini's derivative, i.e. Is

$\displaystyle D_v^- f = \liminf_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+hv ) - f(x)}h \ge 0, \  \mbox{for all} \ x$
?

The first statement implies that it holds almost everywhere, and my intuition is that it is true for all $x$. However, any hint for a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. The key fact to be proved is that for every fixed $x$, the function $g(h) = f(x+hv)$ of variable $h\in\mathbb R$ is nondecreasing.

Since $f$ is continuous, it suffices to prove the above for a dense subset of $x$-values. Using Fubini's theorem, you can show that for almost every $x$, the line through $x$ in direction $v$ meets the set $\{x: \not\exists\nabla f(x)\}$ in a set of linear measure zero. Fix such $x$. The function $g$ is Lipschitz with nonnegative derivative a.e.; it follows that $g$ is nondecreasing.

**Added**: I was a bit vague about Fibini above; here is a more precise explanation. To use Fubini's theorem, we need a product space. Write $\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^{n-1}\times \mathbb R$ where the last coordinate is parallel to $v$. (We can choose such a coordinate system.) Write $x\in\mathbb R^n$ in product notation $x=(x',x_n)\in \mathbb R^{n-1}\times \mathbb R$. Then 
 $$0=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\chi_N(x)\,dx = \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \int_{\mathbb R} \chi_N(x',x_n)\,dx_n\,dx'  = \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \mu_1(N\cap L_{x'})  dx' $$
where $L_{x'}$ is the line through $x'$ in direction $v$. Thus, for almost every $x'$ the intersection $N\cap L_{x'}$ has linear measure zero. For such $x'$, the function $g(h)=f(x'+hv)$ is nondecreasing. By continuity of $f$, we have the same for all $x'$.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment.,  but if you excuse me: what does Fubini theorem have to do with this?

Comment: @m.a There is a null set N on which the gradient does not exist. This is a concern, because I want to consider the restriction of function to a line, using the information about the gradient. So I want the intersection of the line with N to have linear measure zero. This does not have to happen on every line. But applying Fubini's theorem to the characteristic function of N tells me that for almost every line the intersection is indeed of measure zero.

Comment: My comment is at http://i.imgur.com/bdLGIfp.png

Comment: @M.A And my comment is added to the answer. :)

Comment: Thank very much for the answer